# How to represent the following data structure in scheme r5rs

Tags: scheme, racket, custom-data-type, data-representation

In Python the data structure looks like this: `[([1 2 3], [8 9 10])]` (a list of tuple, where tuple is of size 2, and each tuple element is a list again)

How would I represent the same in Scheme r5rs?

This is what I tried: `` (list (cons `(1 2 3) `(8 9 10))) ``

But running `` (display (list (cons `(1 2 3) `(8 9 10)))) ``  gives `(((1 2 3) 8 9 10))` whereas I want `(((1 2 3) (8 9 10)))`

**Edit**
Using only lists (as per @Will Ness answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507876/4947985)):

```
  (list             ; a pair of elements, 
    (list 1 2 3)      ; 1      each is itself
    (list 8 9 10)))   ; 2        a list
```

works.
And I can access the 2nd element of the tuple by
`(cadr (car x))` which gives `(8 9 10)` (which is correct)

I was just thinking how would I build this up using `cons` since my tuple will only contain 2 elements and from what I know `cons` are used to represent a pair in Scheme. Any ideas on how to do this using `cons`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[([1 2 3], [8 9 10])]` (a list of tuple, where tuple is of size 2, and each tuple element is a list again)

```
(list              ; a list of
  (list             ; a pair of elements, 
    (list 1 2 3)      ; 1      each is itself
    (list 8 9 10)))   ; 2        a list
```

Scheme is untyped, so we can just use lists for tuples. It is simpler that way -- the access is uniform. The first is `car`, the second `cadr`.

Your way is correct as well. What really determines whether it is or not is how you can access your data to retrieve its constituents back. And with your way you can indeed, too: the first element will be `car` and the second -- `cdr`.

(update to the question edit:) whether you use `(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))` or `(list 1 2)` is immaterial. the resulting structure in memory is the same.

Comment: Is it possible to represent the tuple as a pair (in scheme) because when i do this:
`(display (cdr (car x)))`

i get: `((8 9 10))`

but what i would like is the 2nd element of tuple i.e: `(8 9 10)`

where x is what you have written in your answer

Comment: with my way we get back the first element as `(car (car x))` and the second as `(cadr (car x))`. Like I wrote, `car` for first and `cadr` for second. While the "tuple" itself is the first element in the outer list, i.e. its `car`.

Comment: Ohk, didn't know about cadr function, that makes it neater to access. Thanks!

Comment: so, not `cdr` like you wrote, but `car`. and with _your_ definition, it indeed would be `cdr`. (except, don't use backticks there, use regular ticks, `'`).

Comment: `(cadr x)` === `(car (cdr x))`. `(cdaddr x)` === `(cdr (car (cdr (cdr x))))`. etc. (up to 4 letters `a` and `d` in any order, between `c` and `r`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinity of ways to represent data.  You have been presented a way.  Here is other way:

```
(define mk/data
  (lambda (a b)
    (lambda (?)
      (cond ((eq? ? 'repr) (list (list a b)))
            ((eq? ? 'first) a)
            ((eq? ? 'second) b)))))

(define data/test (mk/data '(1 2 3) '(8 9 10)))

(data/test 'repr)
(data/test 'first)
(data/test 'second)
```

This is another way how the big systems actually represent data.

Comment: nice, but you've made your data immutable.

Comment: Oh, I am working on a C project now and I wanted to be brief.  He can add dispatcher for mutation, if he needs...